# Can't get notification on Production server while existing app on App Store getting notification

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning

I want to update existng iOS app in app store. I have a problem that when I install iOS client with Distribution certificate on device I don't getting notification while in test I do. here's what going on:

We have **Test server** with certificate to send notification. in Apple member center I have certificates:

- iOS development
- APN's Development iOS
- profile `DevelopmentMyApp` that works with that certificate

Also I have the same thing on the **Production Server**:

- iOS Distribution

  APN's Production iOS

  and a profile `DistrMyApp` in Distribution category that connected to
  that certificate.

The DEV/PRO working with the *same bundle* and *id*.
The problem is when I compile to work with the **Test server** I'm getting notifications without any problem, but when I changing it to **Production server** and sign it with the `DistrMyApp`  profile the app complies, but I never getting notification on my device.

I thought maybe we have problems with certificates on the production server so I installed the same app that already exist in app store and uses this certificate and tried to send notification - all works!!

I cant understand what is the problem, when I compile it to PRO I dont get anythign but when I download app that already uses this certificate all works good.

How can I check that my version for production will work good with notification before uploading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificates and profiles were good, the problem was that when you compile it as `AD-HOC` you can install it only *through iTunes or other distribution services* so the push notification will work. Installing it from Xcode wont work! it's not a real `AD-HOC` deployment

strange, but that is the answer.